# Confusion regarding concept of covariance of electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, covariance

I was reading Jackson(p. 556-557 3rd edition), where I got confused about covariance of electrodynamics. The equation of electrodynamics are written in 'contravariant' tensor then why we call them covariance of elctrodynamics?

$\partial_\alpha F^{\alpha\beta}  = \frac{4\pi}{c} J^{\beta}$

similarly we have another equation,

$\partial_\alpha F^{\alpha\beta} = 0$

In this both equations you can see the tensor is contravariant so how could we say that this is covariance of electrodynamics?

And why we are taking covariant derivative

$\partial_\alpha$

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a definition of covariance you know?

Comment: when we change the basis, the tensor components which transformed as according same way as that of change of basis.   Unlike in contravariant we go by opposite way. means we transformed opposite way of how basis are transformed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manifest covariance means the right hand side of the equation has the same transformation properties as the left hand side, which of course means the equation is valid after any transformation.

Comment: To reinforce the answer by JEB: "Covariance," as in "the theory is covarant,"  has nothing to with covariant and contravariant tensors.

Comment: oh i got that covariance is a thing that does not change with coordinate transformation. means coordinate invariance.